# The GRPC doesn't work in distributed Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, grpc

I'm running a distributed Tensorflow script. When creating cluster server, I see some information appear in the console that look like the following:

> E0805 20:51:03.294260965    3387 ev_epoll1_linux.c:1051]     grpc epoll fd: 3
>
> 2017-08-05 20:51:03.299766: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> localhost:2222}
>
> 2017-08-05 20:51:03.299790: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> localhost:2223}
>
> 2017-08-05 20:51:03.305220: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:316] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2223

When training, I encounter same information and no other response.

> E0805 20:52:45.889979901    3387 ev_epoll1_linux.c:1051]     grpc epoll fd: 3

The information is printed from `with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2223") as sess:`

The version of Tensorflow : `1.3.0-rc0` , which compiling with bazel and working well for single machine

The version of Linux : `Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty`

The Active Internet connects is :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8321/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2223            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8883/python
```

Here is sample code of creating cluster server

```
def main(_):
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                         job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                         task_index=FLAGS.task_index)
    server.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

and traning code

```
train_X = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
train_Y = train_X * 0.1 + 0.3

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    w = tf.Variable(0.0)
    b = tf.Variable(0.0)
    y = w * X + b
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - Y))

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2223") as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for i in range(500):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: train_Y, Y: train_Y})
        print("after sess.run train")
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print i, sess.run(w), sess.run(b)

print sess.run(w)
print sess.run(b)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: where are you defining the `ps` tasks.?

Comment: The defining code is as follow：  

ps_hosts = [ "localhost:2222"]
worker_hosts = ["localhost:2223"]
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

Comment: Are you also starting other binaries to serve as parameter servers?

Comment: have you find the solution? I also met same problem